# Tic-tac-toe game in Python

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am new to Python. Please help me know what's wrong with my code. I used:

- `display_board()` - [To display board]
- `play_game()` - [Includes all other functions]
- `handle_turns()` - [Used to handle iterations]
- `winning_condition()` - [Includes `row_condition()`,
  `column_condition()`, `diagonal_condition()`]
- `game_draw()` - [Check if it's a tie]
- `choose_player()` - [Choose between "X" or "O"]

For first iteration itself its giving result as "Draw".

Seems I'm missing something in play_game() or game_draw() functions.

Below is my code so far:

```py
#our board is a list
list = ['_', '_', '_',
        '_', '_', '_',
        '_', '_', '_']

def display_board():
    print('|' + list[0] + '|' + list[1] + '|' + list[2] + '|')
    print('|' + list[3] + '|' + list[4] + '|' + list[5] + '|')
    print('|' + list[6] + '|' + list[7] + '|' + list[8] + '|')

winner = None
game_on = True
current_player = "X"

#Play game
def play_game():
    display_board()
    while game_on:
        handle_turns(current_player)
        winning_condition()
        game_draw()
        choose_player()
    #when the game over, tell us who won the game or its a draw
    if winner == 'X'or winner == 'O':
        print(f'{winner} won')
    elif winner == None:
        print("Draw")

#Function for winning game
def handle_turns(player):
    turns = 0
    #First player is "X, second player is "Y
    #Display which player's turn it is
    print(f"{player}'s turn")
    i = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    turns = False
    while not turns:
    # turns must be between 1-9, if choosen above 9, then ask player to choose between 1-9
        while i not in range(9):
            i = input("choose between 1 to 9: ")
        i = int(i) - 1
        #if list index value is '_', then we are good to play
        if list[i] == '_':
            turns = True
        else:
            #if list index value is filled with "X" or "O", then we should choose another index
            print("Invalid move, play again")
    #Assign player to our list
    list[i] = player
    display_board()

#This function includes row_condition, column_condition and diagonal_condition
def winning_condition():
    global winner
    row_win = row_condition()
    column_win = column_condition()
    diagonal_win = diagonal_condition()
    if row_win:
        winner = row_condition()
    elif column_win:
        winner = column_condition()
    elif diagonal_win:
        winner = diagonal_condition()
    else:
        winner = None

def row_condition():
    global game_on
    if (list[0] == list[1] == list[2] or list[3] == list[4] == list[5] or list[6] == list[7] == list[8]) != '_':
        game_on = False
     #First row
    elif (list[0] == list[1] == list[2]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[0]
    #Second row
    elif (list[3] == list[4] == list[5]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[3]
    #Third row
    elif (list[6] == list[7] == list[8]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[6]
    else:
        return None

def column_condition():
    global game_on
    if (list[0] == list[3] == list[6] or list[1] == list[4] == list[7] or list[2] == list[5] == list[8]) != '_':
        game_on = False
    #First Column
    elif (list[0] == list[3] == list[6]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[0]
    #Second Column
    elif (list[1] == list[4] == list[7]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[1]
    #Third column
    elif (list[2] == list[5] == list[8]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[2]
    else:
        return None

def diagonal_condition():
    global game_on
    if (list[0] == list[4] == list[8] or list[2] == list[4] == list[6]) != '_':
        game_on = False
    #Diagonal1
    elif (list[0] == list[4] == list[8]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[0]
        #Diagonal2
    elif (list[2] == list[4] == list[6]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[2]
    else:
        return None

#When game is draw
def game_draw():
    global game_on
    if '_' not in list:
        game_on = False
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Choose between X or O
def choose_player():
    global current_player
    # choosing between "X"s or "O"s turns
    if current_player == "X":
        current_player = "O"
    elif current_player == "O":
        current_player = "X"

play_game()
```

Comment: I suggest renaming the name of the list variable as it is a built-in function in python. Call it something like "board".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the parentheses, for example let's evaluate the condition `(list[0] == list[1] == list[2]) != '_'` from `row_condition()` at the start of the game:

```py
(list[0] == list[1] == list[2]) != '_'
('_' == '_' == '_') != '_'
('_' == '_' and '_' == '_') != '_'
(True and True) != '_'
(True) != '_'
True != '_'
True
```

To solve this problem you need to get rid of the parentheses:

```py
list[0] == list[1] == list[2] != '_'
'_' == '_' == '_' != '_'
'_' == '_' and '_' == '_' and '_' != '_'
True and True and False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def row_condition():
    global game_on
    # need to change here!
    if (list[0] == list[1] == list[2] or list[3] == list[4] == list[5] or list[6] == list[7] == list[8]) != '_':
        game_on = False
     #First row
    elif (list[0] == list[1] == list[2]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[0]
    #Second row
    elif (list[3] == list[4] == list[5]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[3]
    #Third row
    elif (list[6] == list[7] == list[8]) != '_':
        game_on = True
        return list[6]
    else:
        return None
```

you need change the first condition

```
> (list[0] == list[1] == list[2] or list[3] == list[4] == list[5] or list[6] == list[7] == list[8])
True or False

> True != "_"
True
> False != "_"
True
```

Comment: Thank you @mustnot, I created variables for each row, column and diagonal and it worked.